# Seek bar chromecast

Tags: android, casting, youtube-api, chromecast, sender

I am making chromecast sender app in android. I checked youtube app, where  user cast any vedio, then vedio play on TV screen but never on android device. Only seek bar moves as vedio play further. 
How can i implement such a work around in my app.

So far what i have done is, my vedio is playing on youtube vedio player(while casting). I cant overlay any widget on youtube vedio player(so that vedio part hides and only seekbar is visible)  since it doesn't allow(it pause the vedio if i do so).

So how to implement such UI functionality in my app.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sender app should not have content playing at all while casting. You need to set up a listener on your sender to check for the progress of your media. You should refer to the [GitHub samples](https://github.com/googlecast) and use those as a base. For [Android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android), you will also need the [Cast Companion Library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android), which should help take care of a lot of the more mundane tasks and components.

Comment: Yes that is the main problem. I am having vedio Id of youtube vedios which i can only play on youtube vedio player. And then vedio will also come along with seek bar . What i want is only seek bar of player and any static image show on player view. I can capture all events of youtube player but how to do it with using only seek bar widget of android .  "You need to set up a listener on your sender to check for the progress of your media" that you said but how to do this.